# Regex to match string of limited length and if number digit are present it can't be more than 5 digit

Tags: regex

im looking for regex that can match string with requirement below.

- must be 5 to 15 characters
- Alphanumeric, can accept fully alphabet, if numeric are present, it must not exceed 5 digit and it can be in anywhere in the string.

Example accepted input

- helloworld
- 123helloworld56
- 1h2e3l4l5oworld
- 12345

if the numeric digit exceeded 5 it shall be rejected. Example rejected input:

- 123456
- 123hello4567

So far i have tried while looking online and done some tweaking, but none work as expected.

```
^(?=.*\d?.*\d?.*\d?.*\d?.*\d?).{0,15}$
^(?=[a-zA-Z1-9]{5,15}$)[a-zA-Z]{1,15}[1-9]{0,5}$
^(?=.*\d){0,5}.{0,15}$
```

I have stuck on this for some time now, any help are appreciated!

Comment: You can use a negative lookahead asserting not 6 digits `^(?!(?:[^\d\r\n]*\d){6})[a-z0-9]{5,15}$` https://regex101.com/r/pmrxSJ/1

Comment: What programming language do you use here?

Comment: @Jan im using c# here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there can not be more than 5 digits in total, that means you should not be able to match 6 digits.

You can use a negative lookahead to assert what is on the right can not match 6 digits.

```
^(?!(?:[^\d\r\n]*\d){6})[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,15}$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert what is at the right is not

  - `(?:[^\d\r\n]*\d){6}` Match 6 times any char except a newline or a digit, then match a digit
- `)` Close lookahead
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,15}` Match 5-15 times any of the listed in the character class
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iZ0SwS/1)

Note that using `[1-9]` in a character class does not match the 0, and `\d` will

---

**About the patterns in the question**

- `^(?=.*\d?.*\d?.*\d?.*\d?.*\d?).{0,15}$`

Here, the lookahead will always be true as all the parts in it are optional. It could also match an empty string as the quantifier `{0,15}` starts at 0, which makes it optional.

- `^(?=[a-zA-Z1-9]{5,15}$)[a-zA-Z]{1,15}[1-9]{0,5}$`

The pattern asserts a string with 5-15 times any of the listed in the character class. But the matching starts with 1-15 times a char a-zA-Z followed by matching 0-5 times a digit at the end of the string.

- `^(?=.*\d){0,5}.{0,15}$`

The pattern optionally asserts 0-5 digits which is always true as it is optional. Then it matches 0-15 times any char.

Comment: Thanks for the solution and explanation, you even gone the extra miles to describe why the previous regex is not working. Thanks again!